# How to write Single Xpath instead of Multiple

Tags: typescript, selenium, xpath, protractor

I am using protractor with type script. I have an element at:

```
xpath = "**//div[@class='loglist']/div[1]/div[2]**"
```

Subsequently I have other elements to identify at different div's as:

```
**/div[2]/div[2]**, **/div[3]/div[2]**, /**div[4]/div[2]**,
```

keeping only the div part changing

How do I write this all up in one single `xpath` instead of multiple xpaths?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Elements in different div's are BY DEFINITION going to be at a different xpath... Please try to state your problem in a clearer way, and show any attempts at achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
_locator = function (i, k) {
  return "//div[@class='loglist']/div[" + i + "]/div[" + k "]"
}
element(by.xpath(_locator(1,2)))
```

But this is in javascript, I think you can take it from here and make analogy with TS